# Getting Average Execution Time of a Program

Tags: average, mean, execution-time, standard-deviation, cumulative-sum

I am trying to get the total execution time of a program - running it different times will give different run times since it depends on a lot of factors. Thus, I am running this program multiple times and taking the mean running time. Is there a way to determine what is the optimal number of times this program should be run because running it too many times will lead to the waste of precious resources, while running it too little times will not allow me to gain reliable insights?

Comment: It depends how much detail you need. Really not possible to answer the question without knowing what you are intending to do with the information, what the sources of variation are, and so on.

Comment: Do you want; Fastest time? Slowest? Median? Arithmetic mean? Geometric mean? Harmonic mean? Typical slowest time (discarding outliers)? Do you want a single number, or to characterise the distribution?

Comment: So in order to answer the question, you must first ensure you know what you mean by the question. What action do you intend to take based on the number? What will you do differently if the number is big versus if it is small? And why?

Comment: Answering those questions in a few short sentences will probably let you see immediately what numbers you need to gather. If not, edit your question and I am sure someone can help.

Comment: I want to find the geometric mean. I want to do this to be able to compare the execution time of different solutions for the same problem so that I can determine which one of them is the most optimal with regards to the running time. The input will always be the same.

Comment: Are you reliant on external resources which may go wrong, e.g. network calls? Or just local resources like disks and memory?

Comment: Local resources only

Comment: This is a statistical question.